# How To add import button in custom grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport

```
I have to use this link for add import button in custom grid.
```

[How to add Upload Button for importing a csv file in the Custom Admin Grid Container?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123813/how-to-add-upload-button-for-importing-a-csv-file-in-the-custom-admin-grid-conta)

```
but I don't know how to add its action?
```

it is my makemodel.php file

```
<?php

class Sigmasolve_Makemodel_Block_Adminhtml_Makemodel extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_makemodel';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'makemodel';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('makemodel')->__('Item Manager');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('makemodel')->__('Add Item');
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_addButton("Import", array(
            "label" => Mage::helper("core")->__("Import"),
            "onclick" => "location.href = '" . $this->getUrl('makemodel/adminhtml_import') . "';",
            "class" => "btn btn-danger",
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make "**Import**" **controller** and "**index**" as shown below:-

```
class YourPackageName_YourModuleName_Adminhtml_ImportController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action{
   public function indexAction() {
      //your import codes write here
    }
}
```

Comment: can i set the save action in this file for import csv?

Comment: sure . then your action url should be `$this->getUrl('makemodel/adminhtml_import/save')`

Comment: How did yoy saved it any idea